# How to minimize all windows from command line in LXDE?

Tags: command-line, windows, lubuntu, lxde, minimize

I need to minimize all windows from command line, I have heard about

```
wmctrl -k on
```

but I think it will only work for gnome, is there any possibility of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

Your command, `wmctrl -k on` is respected by Openbox which is the window manager used in LXDE and it works for me (Openbox session of Lubuntu 14.04 LTS).

If it doesn't work for some reason, install `xdotool` from the software center and use this command:

```
xdotool key super+d
```

What this command does is the same as simultaneously pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> which is the Openbox toggle for minimizing all windows or showing all windows unless you've modified your `lxde-rc.xml` or `lubuntu-rc.xml` or `rc.xml`, a file normally located in `~/.config/openbox`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also minimize all window using `wmctrl -k on`

if it is not work, install `wmctrl` using `sudo apt install wmctrl`